# Python is not fetching username from my .env file in windows

Tags: python-2.7

1)  !pip install python-dotenv

2)  from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

3)  # find .env automatically by walking up directories until it's found
    dotenv_path = find_dotenv()
    # load up the entries as environment variables
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

4)  import os
    KAGGLE_USERNAME = os.environ.get("KAGGLE_USERNAME")
    print(KAGGLE_USERNAME)

```
Output: None
```

But

Expected output is:

what is the issue here?

Comment: I recommend you try re-editing your question so the code is formatted properly.  Also you don't mention what your expected output _is_.

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced this issue.

Problem was i was running this inside a virtual environment and the dotenv package fails to locate the .env file using find_dotenv() command. To overcome this use

```
dotenv_path = find_dotenv(usecwd=True)
```

Hopefully this will work.